# JavaScript to TypeScript type/interface mapping

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using [this](https://github.com/hawkeye64/onvif-nvt/blob/master/lib/camera.js) library in a TypeScript project.
And this is how my class looks like:

```
import OnvifManager from 'onvif-nvt'
Class OnvifApi {
// device: any = undefined
device = {} as OnvifDevice
constructor (...params) {
// definition
}
connect (): Promise<any> {
  OnvifManager.connect(...params).then((response: OnvifDevice) => {
    this.device = response
    resolve(response)
  }
}
coreService(): Promise<Type[]> {
  this.device.add('core')
}
}
```

And this this interface I created for the response from `onvif-nvt`

```
interface OnvifDevice {
  address: string
  // type
  // type
  // type
  add(name: string): void
}
```

This class is always giving an error in `coreService` saying that

> `this.device.add` is not a function.

EDIT: [This](https://github.com/hawkeye64/onvif-nvt/blob/master/lib/onvif-nvt.js#L64) is the return of the `connect` method, which returns the whole Camera object.

Things are working when `device` is defined to `any`.

How can I do this interface mapping from JavaScript to TypeScript?

[image: Response from connect]

Comment: Are you sure the `connect` is giving you an object with an `add` function? That runtime error would seem to indicate otherwise. Have you debugged to check what the `response` object is?

Comment: Have you also checked to make sure `coreService` is not called before `connect` resolves?

Comment: Please don't use images to show textual information. Use text to show textual information.

Comment: I added the response object in question. 
And yes, coreService is called after connect resolves. Everything works when `device` is of type `any`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `device: OnvifDevice = {}` instead of `device = OnvifDevice = {}`? Or what are you trying to do here? And why is `Class` uppercase?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry; but the response is pretty big, and I just wanted to show this specific add method which is not working.

Comment: @A_A Thanks, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Seems to work: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAeQHYDdgDMCyBDJ2DmAplHOlBCHAOQSoYC0qMVAUC8EjMetgMaGI66ACKE0-OAG8WcONgAm8qIQDOKgFxwVMKB3wy5igBR4QhTdt1J8ASk0oIweSwC+LGAE8wAgCpeBALxaOnpsvAA22GqCaOgAgmDAUgYA9Clw8mLA-Jq4HnBBAK5ImegchM6ymeKBUi5yKjEYojUGvLSWhbww0HBGNsmyaRmEZUjAMMC0Bm6y7UhIhN19AHRrYNhQ2CAackgeANoAunZwAArkIMAqhAA8eQB8g7JwyjCFUEhwiwDu55fXQhGIzKFQQcIoQgAGlehAAVksYAMAk9pC8XshYjg8EQoCt5otukY1isNlsdjYVjAABaEJDA0GQJA3TSY5pZfjI1EGdGyGnXFbVbK1RkdQg83mg8GQkGqJk3GwS2QuRXolUzNrQQgAZWINX6mguFEBtz83mO3PR-JUgo5hBWCnkRio7WUVFVLzeHy+RquNxWUohQIOVHQEAgVBOGpcQA)

Comment: Or is it a runtime error, @nirvair?

Comment: I didn't say "copy all text from your response and paste it into your question". Certainly you can prune the response as text by selecting and deleting the unneeded text?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, in the interface, OnvifDevice, add is a mandatory parameter, but the device object is initialised with an empty object.

The dynamic mapping at `this.device = response` is not happening.
Also please check if the response has add method or not while you debug.

These are the two possible symptoms I see.